# python will not let another program write test report to .txt file while its running

Tags: python

I have an automated RAM tester that writes a test report for each Module it tests. the RAM tester keeps adding to the test report indefinitely. What I want to do is have Python read the report and look for the word "PASS" and the speed of the RAM.

Once the two words are found, I need Python to write to the serial port and clear the report so there is nothing in the .txt file. That way it is ready to loop around and read the next report from the next module tested.

The code is all written besides when Python is running the RAM tester will not write its report to the`.txt`file. I have created a small program that takes a test report I captured from the RAM tester and writes it to the .txt file every 3 seconds and that works perfectly.

The program I am working on opens the`.txt`file, finds the text my other program wrote to it, finds the 2 key words, deletes them, loops around and does it until I close the program like I want it to. I have done some trouble shooting with it by commenting out chunks of code and everything works until it runs the

```
file = open("yup.txt", "r+")
txt = file.read()
```

part, then the RAM tester fails to write the report. I think that loop is screwing it up by constantly accessing/reading the`.txt`file...not too sure though. Also Python does not crash at all it just sits there in the loop so I have no problems as far as that goes.

Here is the code I'm having troubles with:

```
cache_size = os.lstat("yup.txt").st_size
print '\nsearching for number of characters in cache\n'
time.sleep(2)

if cache_size == 0:
    print ('0 characters found in cache!\n')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print ('there is no data to process!\n')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print ('waiting for RAMBot\n')

if cache_size > 0:
    print '%d characters found in cache!' % (cache_size)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print ('\ndata analysis will now begin\n')

print('________________________________________________________________________________')

x = 1
while x == 1:

    file = open("yup.txt" ,  "r+")
    txt = file.read()

    if "PASS" and '@2x400MHZ' in txt:
        ser.write('4')
        print('DDR2 PC-6400 (800MHz) module detected')
        open('yup.txt' , 'w')
        file.close()

    if "PASS" and '@2x333MHZ' in txt:
        ser.write('3')
        print('DDR2 PC-5300 (667MHz) module detected')
        open('yup.txt' , 'w')
        file.close()

    if "PASS" and '@2x266MHZ' in txt:
        ser.write('2')
        print('DDR2 PC-4200 (533MHz) module detected')
        open('yup.txt' , 'w')
        file.close()

    if "PASS" and '@2x200MHZ' in txt:
        ser.write('1')
        print('DDR2 PC-3200 (400MHz) module detected')
        open('yup.txt' , 'w')
        file.close()
```

Here is a one of the test reports from the RAM tester:

```
Test No.: 1
Module      : DDR2 256Mx72 2GB 2R(8)@2x333MHZ 1.8V
        (Tested at 2x400MHz)
Addr.(rowxcol.) : 14 x 10
Data (rankxbit) :  2 x 72
Internal Banks  :  8
Burst   : Mode=Sequential, Length=8
AC parameters   : CL=5, AL=0, Trcd=5, Trp=5
S/N from SPD    : a128f4f3
Test Loop # : 1
Test Pattern    : wA, wD, mt, mX, mC, mY, S.O.E
## PASS:   Loop 1 ##
Elapsed Time    : 00:00:53.448
Date    : 09/26/2014, 16:07:40
```

Am not sure if this helps or not but here is the small program that I wrote to simulate the RAM tester writing its test reports to the`.txt`file. I am still confused on why this works and the RAM tester writing the test report has problems...

```
import os
import time

Q = '''Test No.: 1
Module      : DDR2 256Mx72 2GB 2R(8)@2x333MHZ 1.8V
        (Tested at 2x400MHz)
Addr.(rowxcol.) : 14 x 10
Data (rankxbit) :  2 x 72
Internal Banks  :  8
Burst   : Mode=Sequential, Length=8
AC parameters   : CL=5, AL=0, Trcd=5, Trp=5
S/N from SPD    : a128f4f3
Test Loop # : 1
Test Pattern    : wA, wD, mt, mX, mC, mY, S.O.E
## PASS:   Loop 1 ##
Elapsed Time    : 00:00:53.448
Date    : 09/26/2014, 16:07:40'''

x = 1
while x == 1:
    host = open('yup.txt' , 'w')
    host.write(Q)
    host.close()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Thank you very much in advance, I **really** need to get this to work so it is much appreciated.

Comment: First, is any of the Arduino stuff actually relevant here? Can you write a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that just has two scripts reading and writing, say, auto-incrementing numbers to the file, instead of talking to Arduino and reading and writing RAM dumps from it? Because then, a lot more people would (a) be willing to read your question, and (b) be able to test it themselves.

Comment: Second, what platform are you running your code on? If this is Windows, opening a file in write mode by default means an exclusive lock, which means if anyone else tries to open it, even in read mode, it will fail.

Comment: @abarnert I am running Windows for this, I notice you say it is locked by default, is there any way to turn off the lock?

Comment: Not easily. Let me write an answer.

Comment: You can do the `file.close()` immediately after the `txt = file.read()`. Also you never write anything to the `yup.txt` file after opening it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that on Windows, two programs generally can't have the same file open at the same time. When you try to open the file in `w` or `r+` mode, you're asking it to open the file for exclusive access, meaning it will fail if someone else already has the file open, and it will block anyone else from opening the file.

If you want the specifics on sharing and locks in Windows, see the `dwShareMode` explanation in the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) function on MSDN. (Of course you're not calling `CreateFile`, you're just using Python's `open`, which calls `CreateFile` for you—or, in older versions, calls [`fopen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx), which itself calls `CreateFile`.)

---

So, how do you work around this?

The simplest thing to do is just not keep the file open. Open the file, write it, and close it again. (Also, since you never write to `file`, why open it in `r+` mode in the first place?)

You will also have to add some code that handles an `OSError` caused by the race condition of both programs trying to open and write the file at the exact same time, but that's just a simple `try:`/`except:` with a loop around it.

---

Could you just open the file with more permissive sharing?

Sure. You could, for example, use [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to call `CreateFile` and `WriteFile` instead of using Python's `open` and `write` wrappers, and then you can pass any parameters you want for `dwShareMode`.

But think about what this means. What happens if both programs try to write the file at the same time? Who wins? If you're lucky, you lose one test output. If you're unlucky, script A blanks the file halfway through script B writing its test output, and you get a garbage file that you can't parse and throw an indecipherable and hard-to-reproduce exception. So, is that really what you want?

---

Meanwhile, you've got some other weird stuff in your code.

Why are you opening another handle to the same path just to truncate it? Why not just, say, `file.truncate(0)`? Doing another `open` while you still have `file` open in `r+` mode means you end up conflicting with yourself, even if no other program was trying to use the same file.

You're also relying on some pretty odd behavior of the file pointer. You've read everything in `file`. You haven't seeked back to the start, or reopened the file. You've truncated the file and overwritten it with about the same amount of data. So when you `read()` again, you should get nothing, or maybe a few lines if the test reports aren't always the exact same length. The fact that you're actually getting the whole file is an unexpected consequence of some weird things Windows does in its C stdio library.

Comment: thanks for all the info, I'm not at home at the moment so I will have to sit down and try some of your suggestions as soon as I get back. I'm new to python, in fact this is my first project, so I apologize for my obvious mistakes in the code. i may have some questions with adding code to handle oserror as I have never used it before.

Comment: so im looking at everything you've said, and it just dosnt look like there is a 100% perfect way of doing this. the problem is that i am doing this to automate the sorting process of the tested RAM and we test about 4000 modules a day. so even a small margin of error will equate to a big problem. is there anyway you can think of that i can use the amount of characters in yup.txt to signal when to execute the opening of the file? the test report is 404 characters and i already have the variable for the number of bytes in the file (cache_size). or does checking file size lock it too?

Comment: @RollyAponte: First, there's really no margin of error if you just handle collisions with a `try`/`except` and retry. (On Unix, you'd probably actually use `flock` to both programs to _force_ collisions to fail so you could retry them; on Windows, you get that for free.)

Comment: @RollyAponte: But if you want to trigger this script to do its thing when the file changes, the best way to do that is probably to use a filesystem watch API. On Windows, [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417(v=vs.85).aspx) is the place to start looking. Python doesn't have a built-in wrapper around that, but you can use PyWin32 again, or there are multiple cross-platform wrappers on PyPI.

Comment: @RollyAponte: Or, even more simply: You have the program that retrieves the test data and dumps it to a file. It's simple Python code. Why not just have it kick off the processing directly, instead of appending it to a file and fighting with a separate program that tries to process that file?

Comment: i like the processing it directly idea, but i do not know how i would go about that.

Comment: @RollyAponte: Wait, hold on… is the RAM tester actually a Python script? If not, is it being scheduled by a Python script you wrote, or does it do that on its own? If the whole thing is a mess of compiled C code that runs on its own timer that you don't want to look at, then the "processing it directly" thing isn't going to be an answer…

Comment: unfortunately it's not a python script i wrote. the software that generates the test report is software that came with the RAM tester and im not sure what language its written in